# Flash AS3 - Get user location via Google Analytics library

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-analytics, analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics library (AS3 mode) .swc to track some click statistics. 
Now I'ld like to get the users location. Does anyone know if it's possible to do that with the Flash Google Analytics library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so (it's not its purpose) but you can try the main [google loader api](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/loader/) as it usually gives some location info based on your IP (see google.loader.ClientLocation [here](http://www.google.com/jsapi)).

If you need more reliability and/or precision, you can try the [maps api](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/index.html), [gears](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) and/or [html's geolocation apis](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/). I'm pretty sure you can find good examples here in SO.